# Primer cracks once it begins to dry over new Drydex spackling

Tags: drywall, painting, primer, spackling-paste, cracks

Good afternoon,

We are currently working on repainting a bedroom and removed all the items from the wall(pictures, vanity, mirror etc). We completed this and then proceeded to use DryDex 16 oz. Dry Time Indicator Spackling Paste to cover up the holes/issues on the drywall. We then sanded once it was completely dry (24 hours), and wiped down the walls with a wet rag really well so there was no extra dust. We then proceeded to apply Kilz Primer (latex based) to the wall. After a few hours we noticed that the entire area we had applied kilz to that was over the spackling, was peeling!

[image]

We then tried to sand off the peeling pieces, re-spackle the areas that needed it, re-sand/clean off dust, and re-prime to the same results.

Currently at a loss of why this is happening. Both the Drydex and Kilz are brand new from the store. Bedroom is a casual household temperature (68-72). House was built in 1968 if that helps at all. What are we doing wrong and what can we do to be able to lay down paint and have a decent looking wall again? Every site I have seen doesn't seem to have a solid answer or one that we haven't tried (listed below). Thank you.

- We have tried to re-do our work thinking there was a layer of dust on it.
- We have sanded off the peeling pieces, re-spackle the areas that needed it, re-sand/clean off dust, applied a wall texture component to it, then primer with the same peeling results

Comment: `wiped down the walls with a wet rag`

Comment: DAP's Technical Customer Service Department at 888-327-8477

Comment: @jsotola Wet is an overstatement. Slightly damp but enough to get all of the extra dust off. Is your response of the customer service number supposed to be an answer of they need to be contacted instead?

Comment: Did you only cover your repair with Kilz? Try another place in the room NOT repaired and paint some Kilz. This will tell you if your paint is bad or not. If it peels too, contact the manufacturer or return it to the store. If it doesn't peel, then your repair spackle is bad.

Comment: Out of curiousity, I went to DAPs website and looked at reviews. An overall rating of 2.2 for this product, with lots of complaints about paint peel and bubble. I would suspect the spackle to be the issue. I keep a small amount of joint compound for repair purposes, and suggest you return the spackle. Buy a small tub of joint compound, dig the spackle out of the repair, then repair your area with the joint compound, dry, sand, prime, paint.

Comment: We ended up sanding off the peeled pieces, , re-spackling (using same brand but slightly older container I had in the garage), re-sand/clean, SKIPPED priming, and painted directly on it. Paint held without issues and wall looks good now. We are guessing that it was the DAP spackling and we had a bad tub that didn't handle the primer. We used the primer later in the week on a separate area and it held without issues to a different brand of spackling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All,

We ended up sanding off the peeled pieces, , re-spackling (using same brand but slightly older container I had in the garage), re-sand/clean, SKIPPED priming, and painted directly on it. Paint held without issues and wall looks good now. We are guessing that it was the DAP spackling and we had a bad tub that didn't handle the primer. We used the primer later in the week on a separate area and it held without issues to a different brand of spackling.

I honestly believe the overall correct answer would be Jeff Cates comment:
"Out of curiousity, I went to DAPs website and looked at reviews. An overall rating of 2.2 for this product, with lots of complaints about paint peel and bubble. I would suspect the spackle to be the issue. I keep a small amount of joint compound for repair purposes, and suggest you return the spackle. Buy a small tub of joint compound, dig the spackle out of the repair, then repair your area with the joint compound, dry, sand, prime, paint"

Comment: Jeff Cates comment is overall the appropriate answer as I truly believe the underlying issue would was the DAP spackle.

Answer (score 0):

This happened the same to me but it was on my ceiling. I worked on it so much reapply the same spackle and kilz but it kept bubbling and peeling. I finally found this YouTube video of this man explaining why and a product you can use so the chemicals won’t interact with each other and cause the bubbling. All you need to do is first apply this product Pro-999. I did this and it worked great! Hope this help the video was very education and it wasn’t the spackle or paints fault. https://youtu.be/MjZRS4f6MIY

Comment: This could be spam. OTOH, this could be a link-only answer. When that video disappears, this answer becomes useless. Please include some details from the video so people can have at least a general idea of what it covers.